# redirect all request except one url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

in Apache server ,
how can i set Condition and rule to my htaccess file to behave like this :

**url1/search/(blah-blah-blah)** ,
it is OK and no need to redirect but
when user request 
**url1/(blah-blah-blah)** ,
Apache should redirect the request to another site with all URL details like 
**url2.com/(blah-blah-blah)**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^((?!search/).+)$ http://url2.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect all requests to **url2.com** except  **/search/** and **/search/foo/bar** .